# apply css class to "button" inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing a button as below,

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <button id="myBtn" class="myclass">ADD ME</button>
</div>
```

a new attribute gets added to this button from JS and it becomes like below ('disabled' attribute is added)

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <button id="myBtn" class="myclass" disabled="disabled">ADD ME</button>
</div>
```

I'm trying to apply below CSS class for disabled button,

```
#parentDiv button.disabled {
    color: #AAAAAA;
}
```

But to my surprise this class is not getting applied to button.
Please point me the correct direction.

Comment: Can you create a demo?

Comment: I edited the question a while ago, can you please revisit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to add the attribute selector

```
#parentDiv button[disabled="disabled"] 
{
    color:red;
}
```

or just

```
#parentDiv button[disabled] 
{
    color:red;
}
```

```css
#parentDiv button[disabled="disabled"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv">
  <button id="myBtn" class="myclass" disabled="disabled">ADD ME</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS3 selector :disabled

```
#parentDiv button:disabled
{
    color:#AAAAAA;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/8y47anso/1/)**

Comment: why is this answer down-rated? Is this approach not recommended?
The solution given in this answer works perfectly fine. Please comment.

Comment: I really don´t know why! I hope that the moderators see who did that. And make my answer with a up-rated..

Answer (score 0):

Replace your styles with this

```
#parentDiv button:disabled
{
    color:#F00;
}
```

Comment: why is this answer down-rated? Is this approach not recommended?

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute selector `[attr]`

```
#parentDiv button[disabled] {color: #aaa}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f10vfagq/

Answer (score -1):

```
#parentDiv button[disabled]
{
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue